# Remove specific shapes created using paperJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, paperjs

I have created a simple image marker with circle, rectange and line. How can i remove the shapes which i do not need. I have stored co-ordinate points in array. How can i proceed any help. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLzDC/)

Here is the function to push into array

```
function onMouseUp(event) {
            console.log(cPath.points[0]);
            console.log(cPath.downpoints[0]);
            if(set == 1){
                i++;
                circles.push(circle);
                createElem('circle', i);
                cPath.points.push(event.point);
                cPath.downpoints.push((event.downPoint - event.point).length);
            }else if(set == 2){             j++;
                rects.push(rect);
                createElem('rect', j);
            }else if(set == 3){
                k++;
                lines.push(line);
                createElem('line', k);  
            }else if(set == 4){
                l++;
                createElem('Free Path', l);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [paperjs documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference) path has an [remove() method](http://paperjs.org/reference/path#remove) which removes the path from your paperjs document

And as you hold all your items (paths) in arrays, it's relatively easy to remove them from the canvas. Here's an example javascript snippet which will remove all items in given array:

```
function removeItems(items) {
    var len = items.length;
    while(--len < -1) {
       // remove item from the document using paperjs method
       items[len].remove();
       // also remove the item from our own array
       items.splice(len, 1);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PLzDC/3/
here's an fiddle which shows how to remove all rectangles when you draw an circle (it removes them on mouseUp)

**Edit:**

snippet to remove items only having a given name from given array

```
function removeItems(items, name) {
    var len = items.length;
    while(--len < -1) {
       if(items[len].name == name) {
            // remove item from the document using paperjs method
            items[len].remove();
            // also remove the item from our own array
            items.splice(len, 1);
       }
    }
}
```

Usage (considering you actually gave the circle a name 'circle1' on creation):

```
removeItems(circles, 'circle1');
```

Comment: I din't mean this. All shapes should present selectively i have to remove a circle or rectangle etc.,

Comment: Sorry, than I can't understand what you need if you didn't mean this. You want to draw only one from each group? Or hide others while drawing circle? Could you please explain the use-case little bit more

Comment: Ok, Take an example I draw 5 circles name it as circle1, circle2, etc., similarly i draw 5 rectangles name it as rect1, rect2, etc., Now i want to remove only circle2. Can you understand. [Take a reference site](http://picozu.com)

Comment: Just make an if statement in the loop to delete only the item with given name... I edited the function, fiddle is still old. Also you don't actually name any of your paths in the questions code. So before removing them by name, you should name them in the first place.